# transfer the value of a field to variable in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to know how can I store a value in a temp table in SQL Server 2012?
For example:

```
Code    Date         Next day    Last Code
1       01/01/02     01/02/02       0
2       03/01/02     04/02/02       1
```

I only have code, date, next day in my table. How can I save the last code into a field?

Ups, Thanks guy its work but is a large table and I realize that sometimes  we can have same  code for example :
code    last code
0          Null
0          0
1          0 
1          1
2          1
3          2
3          3

Comment: Do you want to get the code from the previous day?

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to what you want to accomplish. What exactly is Last Code. What is the "variable" You mention in the title? Is the whole thing a temp table? Or is Last Code in a temp tbale and you want to add it to this table?

Comment: yes, but I realize that sometime code can repeat for example Code 1   last code 0, code 1 last code 1, code 2 last code 1, code 2 last code 1,,,,

Comment: You need @Gordon's answer.  This will populate the previous code into the current record based on your table order.  You might consider also creating an insert trigger that will handle this every time you insert into that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you really want the `lag()` function:

```
select t.*,
       lag(code) over (order by date) as lastcode
from table t;
```

Note that this would be `NULL` in the first case, because none is defined.  You can use `ifnull()` to assign a value.

In SQL Server, you can use this in an update statement:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             lag(code) over (order by date) as new_lastcode
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set lastcode = new_lastcode;
```

This assumes the column already exists in the table.

Comment: Lag function is a great thought.  I find i'm learning from you constantly.

Comment: @Luis64 . . . Lag is an important part of SQL Server 2012.  Here is the documentation for it:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx.

Comment: 'LAG' is not a recognized built-in function name. every tame I try to use

Comment: @Luis64 . . . Then I don't think you are using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @LastCode INT

SELECT @LastCode = [Last Code]
FROM thatTableExample
WHERE CODE = 2
```